# populate list using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

im working in a project using codeigniter, im trying to fill a dropdown list from database using ajax, but i get erreur :
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

this is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open('patient/nouveau_patient'); ?>

              <input type="text"  name="no_dossier_pt" class="sr-only"  value="" >
              <div class="form-group">

                <label>Patient :</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="patients_list" name="idP">
                  <option>Sélectionner un patient</option>
                </select>

             </div>
             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enregistrer</button>
           <?php echo form_close(); ?>

          </div>
```

this is the code ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var listePatient;
  showRecords();
  function showRecords(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>traitement/aff_patient',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(res){
             listePatient = res.patients;
             var select = document.getElementById("patients_list");
              for(i=select.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
              {
                  select.remove(i);
              }

              for(var i = 0; i < listePatient.length; i++) {
                  var opt = listePatient[i].patient;
                  var opt1 = listePatient[i].id;
                  var el = document.createElement("option");
                  el.textContent = opt;
                  el.value = opt1;
                  select.appendChild(el);
              }
          },
          error: function(){
              alert('Could not load the data');
          },
      });
  }
}

</script>
```

and this is the controller:

```
  public function aff_patient()
     {

         $patients = $this->patient_m->afficher_patients();

          $data_patient = array();

          foreach($patients->result() as $r) {

               $data_patient[] = array(


                    "id" => $r->id,
                    "patient" => $r->nom_pt." ".$r->prenom_pt

               );

           }

         echo json_encode(array("patients" =>$data_patient));
         exit();
     }
```

i thing i did something wrong in my script but im new in ajax 
thanks for helping

Comment: You have to close your function `$(document).ready(function()` in the end of your script with a `)` .

Comment: the last `}` should be `});` - you forgot the bracket. Nothing to do with ajax, just a simple Javascript syntax error. Your browser's tools should have pointed you to the problematic line of code. Likewise a good code editor would have highlighted the missing bracket too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the right syntax of your Ajax :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var listePatient;
  showRecords();
  function showRecords(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>traitement/aff_patient',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(res){
             listePatient = res.patients;
             var select = document.getElementById("patients_list");
              for(i=select.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
              {
                  select.remove(i);
              }

              for(var i = 0; i < listePatient.length; i++) {
                  var opt = listePatient[i].patient;
                  var opt1 = listePatient[i].id;
                  var el = document.createElement("option");
                  el.textContent = opt;
                  el.value = opt1;
                  select.appendChild(el);
              }
          },
          error: function(){
              alert('Could not load the data');
          },
      });
  }
});

</script>
```

As I say you forgot to close your function.

Comment: yes its work now thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome ^^